# how do you say disillusioned using a word "fantasy"?

Tags: grammar, non-native-english

I am writing an essay, but I am having a hard time using the word, fantasy, right.

"I had fantasy about living abroad, but when I arrived there, my fantasy was "

I want to continue with that sentence, I want to use that word, fantasy, since it's a keyword in my essay.

Can I say

1. my fantasy was broken
2. my fantasy broke
3. my fantasy was shattered

What sound most natural to you, native English speakers?

Comment: Though this one doesn't use the fantasy word, apparently there's also an idiom of [burst bubble](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burst+bubble)

Comment: There's another common phrase negating illusions of fantasy. "I had fantasies about living abroad: but when I arrived, reality set in."

Comment: "… my fantasy was **dispelled**" seems like a good choice to me.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should say "I had *a* fantasy about living abroad" or "I had fantas(ies) about living abroad"

I would say that "my fantasy was shattered" would be the most correct and common usage of the phrase.

My fantasy was broken sounds odd, and my fantasy broke is simply incorrect. "My fantasy was shattered" is the correct one.

Please note, if you decided to use the plural "I had fantasies about living abroad" to also change it to "My fantasies were shattered."

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is good, but I would personally avoid using "fantasy" (or fantasies) twice in the same sentence. @rojo's proposal is perhaps the best way to go, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I would use the verb form in the first clause: "I **fantasized** about living abroad, ..."

Answer (score 6):

I would not use fantasy in any of the ways you suggest; while they're understandable I don't think they'd be used that way by a native speaker in my locale (the UK). I would say:

"I had fantas**ies** about living abroad but when I arrived there my **illusions** were shattered."

The phrases "then reality set in", "my bubble was burst", or "I was in for a rude awakening" could also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the context of your question... In Spanish, "Desilusionar" is not cognate in English. Disappointed is a better choice. Also, native speakers would use "dream" rather than fantasy.